# 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type, unwrap

I'd like to do a label which is present only when button is touched. 
When function **hidden()** is called in MainViewController It's working well but when i'm calling it from ButtonAction class (same function) I get an classic error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here's the code:

```
//  MainViewController.swift

import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelToShow: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        labelToShow.isHidden = true
    }

    func hidden() {
        labelToShow.isHidden = true
    }

    func inHidden() {
        labelToShow.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

AND :

```
//  ButtonAction.swift


import UIKit

class ButtonAction: UIButton {

    var touched:Bool = false
    var mainScreen = MainViewController()

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        sleep(1)
        mainScreen.hidden()
        touched = true
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        mainScreen.inHidden()
        touched = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show full code how you create ButtonAction class and ViewController ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

The `mainScreen` instance created with the default initializer  `MainViewController()` is different from those designed in Interface Builder.

You need the actual reference to the main view controller (via `IBOutlet` or protocol / delegate etc.)

Comment: Well, it's not different, it just haven't been set up yet with `InterfaceBuilder` stuff, like setting values to `@IBOutlet`s and adding `@IBAction`s as targets, and other UI stuff like, fonts, colors, etc. All of that can be done in code too.

Comment: I've created protocol and "nil" problem still happend. I've tested protocol with example like print etc and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

In that line of code you are creating a new instance of your MainViewController :

```
var mainScreen = MainViewController()
```

You have to get the reference of your `MainViewController()` instance (created automatically by `storyboard`)